# difference between two dates python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from datetime import date
future = input("Enter a date(dd/mm/yyyy): ")
daystring = future[0:2]
monthstring = future[3:5]
yearstring = future[6:10]

today = (date.today())
month = date.today().month
year = date.today().year
day = date.today().day

if monthstring  == "01" or "03" or "05" or "07" or "08" or "10" or "12":
    if daystring > "31":
        print("Invalid Date Entered")
if monthstring == "04" or "06" or "09" or "11":
    if daystring > "30":
        print("Invalid Date Entered")
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June",
          "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
daysinmonth = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
               31, 30, 31]


if future < today or monthstring > "12":
    print("Invalid Date Entered")

else:
    layout = "%d/%m/%Y"
    a = datetime.strptime(future, layout)
    b = datetime.strptime(today, layout)
    delta = a - b
    print ("The difference between the inputted date and todays date is: ",delta.days, "days")
```

This code is to ask the user to input a date in the future and then the code should use that input and subtract the current date from it.

For example, today is 01/11/2014 and if the user inputs 03/11/2014 the output should be that the difference is 2 days.

However, I'm getting an error every time I input the future date.

Comment: *"i'm getting an error everytime I input the future date"* - **what error?!** If this is Python 2.x you should use `raw_input`. Why on earth do you `import` from `datetime` then manually slice up `future` and try to parse it yourself? Just *use `strptime`*.

Comment: You are comparing strings; did you know that `'9' > '31'` is True when you do that?

Comment: like I said i'm not an expert I just started python so I dont know a lot of stuff

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are different things to be considered. Try to take in considerations these points

- Check if the user is entering right datetime. You can use regular expression to do that. You can use [RE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.

> ```
> mat=re.match('(\d{2})[/](\d{2})[/](\d{4})$', str(future))
> ```

- You should filter values between `1-12` for months, and between `1-31` for days. Then distinguish between months, and don't forget `February` in both cases (leap year or no). You can use `calender` module to check that.

> ```
> t= calendar.monthrange(int(yearstring), 2) # This is to check if February has 29 or 28 (is leap year or no), you can do that by checking the day number of "datetime.date (int(yearstring), 3, 1) - datetime.timedelta (days = 1)"
> ```

- Then, compare between two dates, you should use right time format for every date.

> ```
>  a = date.datetime.strptime(future, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
>  b = date.datetime.strptime(today, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
>  delta = a-b
> ```

Your code would look like:

```
import datetime as date
import re
import calendar

future = input("Enter a date(dd/mm/yyyy): ")
#eg: future="02/03/2015"
#print future

mat=re.match('(\d{2})[/](\d{2})[/](\d{4})$', str(future))
if mat is None:
    print("Invalid Date Entered, try to enter a date in this form(dd/mm/yyyy) ")
else: 
    daystring,monthstring,yearstring= mat.groups()

    today= str(date.datetime.now()).split(" ")[0]
    year, month, day = today.split("-")

    months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June","Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    daysinmonth = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,31, 30, 31]

    if int(daystring)>0 and int(daystring)<=31 and int(monthstring)>0 and int(monthstring) <= 12 and int(yearstring)>0:
        if monthstring  in ["01", "03", "05" ,"07","08","10", "12"]:
            if int(daystring) > 31:
                print("Invalid Date Entered - Number of days can't exceed 31.")
        if monthstring in ["04","06","09","11"]:
            if int(daystring) > 30:
                print("Invalid Date Entered - Number of days can't exceed 31.")
        if monthstring == "02":
            t= calendar.monthrange(int(yearstring), 2) # This is to check if February has 29 or 28 (is leap year or no), you can do that by checking the day number of "datetime.date (int(yearstring), 3, 1) - datetime.timedelta (days = 1)" 
            if int(daystring) !=t: #You forget faberuary 
                print("Invalid Date Entered - of days can't exceed 28 or 29")


        a = date.datetime.strptime(future, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
        b = date.datetime.strptime(today, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        delta = a-b   # The future - Today ::> to get a positive number 
        if delta.days >0:
            print ("The difference between the inputted date and todays date is: ",delta.days, "days")
        else:
            print("Date is in the past")

    else: 
        print("Invalid Date Entered")
```

Comment: There is **absolutely no need** for this. Why would you do all that manual checking of the date? Just guard the call to `strptime` with a `try`, and let the library do the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import dateutil.parser as parser
import datetime
date1 = parser.parse(input("Enter Date:"))
print( (datetime.datetime.now() - date1).days )
```

dateutil is very good at parsing natural date strings ...

you will probably  need to install dateutil

```
easy_install python-dateutil
```

if you want to not use dateutil as mentioned you can use strptime

```
def get_user_date(prompt="Enter Date:"):
    while True:
       try:
          return datetime.datetime.strptime("%m/%d/%y",input(prompt)) 
       except ValueError:
          print( "Invalid Input!" )
```

this code I think will work in python 3